# ORA-00904: "LOCATE": identificador no válido

Tags: sql, oracle

Tengo esta consulta y la estoy ejecutado en Oracle bbdd:

```
SELECT a FROM own_gex.vt_alerta a WHERE (a.exp_centro_asig_nom = 'Hospital Puerto Real' or a.exp_centro_afect_nom = 'Hospital Puerto Real') AND LOCATE(COALESCE(a.novisible_para,' '), 'RCL_RESP_ATCIU')=0
```

pero me da el siguiente error, a qué es debido?

> ORA-00904: "LOCATE": identificador no válido
> 00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
> *Cause:
> *Action: Error en la línea: 1, columna: 145

Comment: Me parece que `LOCATE` no se puede utilizar en Oracle. ¿Y si en su lugar utilizás `INSTR`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No existe ninguna función `locate()` estándar en oracle.

El error es claro: el identificador locate no es válido.

Si lo que buscas es determinar si una cadena contiene otra, como se utiliza en mySQL, puedes cambiar la expresión por la función [`instr()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/INSTR.html)

Algo como:

```
SELECT a.*
  FROM own_gex.vt_alerta a 
 WHERE (    a.exp_centro_asig_nom = 'Hospital Puerto Real' 
         or a.exp_centro_afect_nom = 'Hospital Puerto Real'
       ) 
   AND instr(coalesce(a.novisible_para,' '), 'RCL_RESP_ATCIU')=0
```

Cómo no sé de dónde viene la función `locate()`, te pido que te asegures del orden de los parámetros, en el caso de `instr()` son:

```
instr(cadena, sub_cadena)
```

Por ejemplo:

```
select instr('StackOverflow', 'O') pos from dual;
```

Devuelve

```
pos
---
6
```

Para dejarlo claro, `InStr()` de Oracle acepta los parámetros en distinto orden  a `locate()` de mySQL. Yo no lo he cambiado en el query de ejemplo, porque no sé si tu conocimiento de `locate()` viene de otro lado ni cómo funcione allí.